# How to make my for loop not to show message until it reach the end of array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

How to make my for loop no to show  message until it reach the end of an array.Code is bellow:

```
for (int j = 0; j < logic.rez.length; j++) {

    if (logic.rez[j] >= 20000000 && logic.rez[j] < 23000000) {
        do.this;
        break;
    } else {
        if(logic.rez.length==j){
           rez.append("Error message \n");
    }
}
break;
```

I tried with  set a boolean matchFound to false before the loop, set it to true if you find something, and print error message if it is false after the loop but no luck.I need some condition that will be changed only after the loop makes the end of array

Comment: Why not just print after the loop?

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < logic.rez.length; j++) {} rez.append("Got to end of the array");`

Answer (score 1):

`logic.rez.length==j` will never happen due to your loop only going to `length-1` (that is how less than symbols work). I think you can fix it by doing
`logic.rez.length-1==j`

Comment: While this is true, a better approach would be to handle the error *after* the loop.

Comment: I know, but explaining why it doesn't work is better than fixing it by optimization

Comment: Using a good pattern for linear search is not so much optimization as as avoidance of pessimation. While it is reasonable to address the technical error in the example code, it can be helpful to point out the anti-pattern, and suggest alternatives -- as the OP alluded to in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your logic, the for loop ends once the value of j equals logic.rez.length

```
j < logic.rez.length
```

So the below block of code is redundant-

```
if(logic.rez.length==j) {
    rez.append("Error message \n");
}
```

If you want to capture the condition that the loop reached end of the array, you can -
1) Declare variable j outside the for loop, and have the above block of code after for loop

Answer (score 0):

Although you could check inside the loop whether you've reached the last element, this is not ideal. This approach means you're checking whether you're on the last element every time you go through the loop.

There's a better approach. You know you've reached the end of the loop when control passes to code that follows the loop. You need at most one check for failure, when placed after the loop.

For linear search, there are some recurring patterns for this, including the following.

**Early return when a match is found**

```
int search( Foo[] f ) {
  for ( int i = 0; i < f.length; ++i ) {
     if ( matches( f[i] )) {
        return i;
     }
  }

  return -1;  // Nothing matched. Caller handles error.
}
```

**Inline code with a boolean**

```
boolean foundMatch = false;
for ( int i = 0; i < f.length; ++i ) {
  if ( matches( f[i] )) {
    foundMatch = true;
    // Handle match
    break;
  }
}

if ( ! foundMatch ) { 
  // Nothing matched. Handle error here.
}
```

Comment: But i do not need my loop to end when i find something i need to find value inside my array and if i do not find it then print error message

Comment: @Mapet - The `break` in your sample code will cause your loop to end the first time you find a match. If you want to find all matches, leave out the `break` inside the loop in your sample code and the second pattern above.